# Відповідник до слова "адаптер"

Tags: вибір-слова, іншомовні-слова

На сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/adapter) шукаючи відповідники до слова "[адаптер](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80)" ("пристрій, який з'єднує між собою інші пристрої з різними способами подання даних, узгоджуючи ці способи шляхом використання відповідних програмних і технічних засобів") наткнувся на такі можливі варіанти як "перехідник" і "пристосовувач", однак в СУМі таких слів немає. Проте, вдалося там знайти таке слово як "[перевідник](http://sum.in.ua/s/perevidnyk)" (пристрій, за допомогою якого що-небудь переводять). На Вікіпедії про це слово також є інформація: "пристрій, за допомогою якого що-небудь переміщають у нове положення, змінюють напрям руху потоків, приладів, знарядь тощо". А якщо подивитися на різновити перевідників, що це слово більше пов'язане із трубопроводами, а не комп'ютерною технікою (слід також зауважити, що інформація там була взята із "Малої гірничої енциклопедії").

Якщо загуглити слово "перехідник", то отримаємо безліч варіантів в онлайн магазинах техніки: "перехідник моніторний", "перехідник Apple", тощо. Також на Вікіпедії вдалося зустріти статтю "[Герметичний стикувальний перехідник](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)", однак в цьому контексті по "перехіднику" переходять люди між модулями МКС.

Щодо "пристосовувача", то вдалося лише знайти статтю "[СПІВВІДНОШЕННЯ СИНОНІМІВ ТА ВАРІАНТІВ У СУЧАСНІЙ КОМП’ЮТЕРНІЙ ТЕРМІНОЛОГІЇ](http://ena.lp.edu.ua/bitstream/ntb/30973/1/11-68-72.pdf)", де він подається синонімом до слова "адаптер".

Отож, чи підходить хоч якесь з наведених мною слів для заміни "адаптера" чи, можливо, в українській мові є інші влучніші варіанти? Щодо "перехідника" та "пристосовувача" у мене є сумніви, бо їх немає в СУМі, а от "провідник" хоч і є там, але я не впевнений, що це те, що потрібно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В СУМ-20 присутнє саме слово ***"адаптер"***, що даж повне право використовувати його як в усному мовлені, так і в офіційних документах.

> ***[АДАПТЕР](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=465&page=20)***  а, ч. 1. Пристрій для зв'язку комп'ютера з периферійними приладами. *Адаптер забезпечує сполучення монітора з
>   комп'ютером і служить для відображення на екрані кольору і графіки* (з
>   наук.-техн. літ.).
>
> 2. Пристрій для перетворення механічних коливань в електричні з метою відтворення механічних записів звуків; звукознімач. *Найкращий рівень
>      запису забезпечує професійний магнітофон, який має вмонтований адаптер
>      для запису з телефонної лінії* (із журн.).
> 3. Пристрій для перетворення електричних сигналів або напруги живлення.

*"Перехідник"* лише частково та не зовсім точно може замінити слово *"адаптер"* (знач.3)

Великий тлумачний словник (ВТС) сучасної української мови

> ***[ПЕРЕХІДНИК](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53407/940302.html)***  1. Муфта для з'єднання циліндричних частин технічного
>   пристрою, що мають різний діаметр.
>
> 2. Складова частина стикувальної системи космічного корабля (станції), що служить для переходу космонавтів; перехідний модуль.
> 3. Пристрій для з'єднання електричної розетки і вилки різних систем, конструкцій.

**[*"Провідник"*](http://sum.in.ua/s/providnyk)** - погоджуюсь з Вами не зовсім тей варіант, який потрібен.

На мою думку краще вживати ***"адаптер"*** або ***"пристосовувач"*** (від ["пристосовувати"](http://sum.in.ua/s/prystosovuvaty))